# ReactNative assembleRelease apk fails to find index.android.js

Tags: cross-platform, react-native

- node 6.11.2
- npm 4.6.1
- react-native-cli: 2.0.1
- react-native: n/a - not inside a React Native project directory (???)
- macOS 10.12.6

Used React Native to create a new app from scratch. npm start works like a charm when using the expo app on my Android and iOS Devices. I'm having troubles to build a release apk for Android. (iOS will be next step.)
I did eject the app and followed the instructions to create a keystore file etc. Everything like it is documented here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html

In android folder: running ./gradlew assembleRelease results to:

```
...
:app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
Scanning 748 folders for symlinks in /Users/xy/myApp_ReactNative/node_modules (13ms)
Scanning 748 folders for symlinks in /Users/xy/myApp_ReactNative/node_modules (16ms)
Loading dependency graph, done.

Cannot find entry file index.android.js in any of the roots: ["/Users/xy/myApp_ReactNative"]

:app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.
> Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 26.813 secs
```

After days of trying out different versions and going back and forward, using commands with sudo and looking up alternatives, I'm getting completly lost. Also wondering why it scans twice... how to solve this?

Comment: I believe I ran into this and found that it worked when I downgraded my RN version to 0.44.0--not a great solution, but worth a try

Comment: Hi kwishnu, thanks for the hint. I tried to downgrade to RN 0.44.0 then nothing worked anymore. I did: npm install react-native@0.44.0 . Because app did not start anymore, I then edited package.json react-native:"0.44.0" and followed red screen hints to delete watchman, rm node-modules and npm install and reset cache. Hours spent, nothing works. // Now created new project with CRNA (rn 0.47.2 it now says me) and copied my app files into - works in expo; still fails to find index.android.js like above.

Comment: Sorry if I led you astray...I've actually never done CRNA/eject, only react-native init myAppName which is the older (like, 6 months ago!) style. Frustrating when this stuff just doesn't work the way it's supposed to, and more-so when it works and then stops working because something changed! Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself like so: after trying on a Windows10 machine I realized that I might not have setup NDK. Started Android Studio on my mac and in the SDK Manager installed "NDK". Add a local.properties file in the 'app' folder with sdk.dir=pathtoyourSDK. After that: it worked!